# getting mdply output to fit a dataframe

Tags: r, plyr

I'm having trouble getting the right results from a `mdply` function from the `plyr` package. I have a data frame:

```
foo <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3],
                  times = 3:5)

foo

  x times
1 a     3
2 b     4
3 c     5
```

and I want a vector,  which will consist of the elements of `foo$x`, each repeated the corresponding number of `foo$times`.

I thought this would be a simple application of `mdply`, of the following sort

```
mdply(foo, rep)
```

but the function is trying to rbind the results together (which obviously fails because they're of different lengths.)

how can I get this function to return a long vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply `rep(foo$x, times = foo$times)`?